# Joining pre-defined, possibly non-existing keys with table data

Tags: mysql, sql, join

In MySQL (or SQL in general), is it possible to generate a list of pre-defined identifiers, joined with matching table data?

Take for instance the following table data, let's call it `my_table`:

```
id | value
---+------
 1 | 'a'
 3 | 'c'
```

Now, I have a list of possible `id` values and would like to get a full list of these values, together with joined data from the table above. With a list `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, the desired result is:

```
item | id   | value
-----+------+------
   1 |  1   | 'a'
   2 | NULL | NULL
   3 |  3   | 'c'
   4 | NULL | NULL
```

Obviously, a query like `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)` yields only results for two rows (values 'a' and 'c').

For a solution, I am thinking along the line of some form of temporary table, fed with the full list of id's (`[1, 2, 3, 4]`) and left joining that with the table data, such as

```
SELECT t1.`item`, t2.`id`, t2.`value`
FROM
   ...
AS t1
LEFT JOIN `my_table` AS t2 ON t2.`id` = t1.`item`
```

But how do I do that?

Is this even possible? Or is it really necessary to compare the result with the initial list in external code? (This would be possible, but not trivial as in my case, the identifiers are not integers)

(The ultimate idea of this, is that I  would like a result set from the DB with all input id's so that I can easily identify the non-existing records)

---

Update: I guess it boils down to the question: how can I get a result set such as

```
id
---
 1
 2
 3
 4
```

from a (My)SQL server *without* having this as data in some table, but from setting the data in some query?

Answer (score 0):

A new approach flashed into my mind... using a `union`.

```
SELECT t1.`item`, t2.`id`, t2.`value`
FROM (
    select 1 as `item`
    union select 2
    union select 3
    union select 4
    ) AS t1
LEFT JOIN `my_table` AS t2 ON t2.`id` = t1.`item`
```

It answers the question, but it remains to be seen whether this is the 'best' answer. It works as long as the list of `item`s is not too long (which is the case for me).

Anyone a better solution?